# Android custom ROM: force software decoders

Tags: android, android-source, android-hardware, android-rom, android-mediacodec

I'm building a ROM from AOSP, running on Nexus 5X (bullhead).
I wish to completely disable hardware audio/video decoders and make the platform route everything through software - to work exactly the same as on emulator.

I've tried editing audio_policy_configuration.xml and media_codecs.xml to remove decoders, however I'm getting error messages in logcat and no audio is being played - I've no idea if this is even the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted by editing the following in hardware/qcom/audio/hal/audio_hw.c:

```
static uint32_t out_get_sample_rate(const struct audio_stream *stream)
{
 /*   struct stream_out *out = (struct stream_out *)stream;

    return out->sample_rate;*/

    return 44100;
}

static uint32_t out_get_channels(const struct audio_stream *stream)
{
    /*struct stream_out *out = (struct stream_out *)stream;

    return out->channel_mask;*/

    return AUDIO_CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
}

static audio_format_t out_get_format(const struct audio_stream *stream)
{
   /* struct stream_out *out = (struct stream_out *)stream;

    return out->format;*/

    return AUDIO_FORMAT_PCM_16_BIT;
}
```